File upload option in jenkins
I want to upload file in jenkin pipeline.
I can see file parameter - https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/
But this looks like working fine when we are working same machine where jenkins is configured.
But, in my case jenkins is configured in remote machine, with ip accessing on different machine. This uploaded file is not coming in jenkins workspace.
Can anybody help me on this.
Thanks.
File upload should work from different system.

Show your pipeline code.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Iterokun, i am not using pipeline code, but using file parmater.  https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/

@Community, Jenkins is configured in some server having IP address (x.x.x.x). Now this is remote machine.
Then i am not accessing jenkins directly from remote machine, instead i am accessing from personal system ( but on same network ) by using http://x.x.x.x:8080 .
So file upload doing from personal system.
So how to handle this situation ?

@Community, file upload doing from personal laptop not from remote machine where jenkins is configured. So ideally it should upload from personal laptop to jenkins workspace.
